# onApplicationEvent() is never invoked on DelayHandler

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Integration Java DSL in my @Configuration class. One of the flows is using DelayHandler with MessageStore, by means of .delay(String groupId, String expression, Consumer endpointConfigurer):

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(errorChannel())
            ...
            .delay(...)
            ...
            .get();
}
```

I was hoping to utilize the reschedulePersistedMessages() functionality of DelayHandler, but I found out the onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) which invokes it is actually never invoked (?)

I'm not sure, but I suspect this is due to the fact DelayHandler is not registered as a Bean, so registerListeners() in AbstractApplicationContext is not able to automatically register DelayHandler (and registration of non-bean listeners via ApplicationEventMulticaster.addApplicationListener(ApplicationListener listener) is not done for DelayHandler.

Currently I'm using a rather ugly workaround of registering my own listener Bean into which I inject the integration flow Bean, and then invoking the onApplicationEvent() manually after locating the DelayHandler:

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    Set<Object> integrationComponents = errorFlow.getIntegrationComponents();
    for (Object component : integrationComponents) {
        if (component instanceof DelayerEndpointSpec) {
            Tuple2<ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean, DelayHandler> tuple2 = ((DelayerEndpointSpec) component).get();
            tuple2.getT2().onApplicationEvent(event);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting... Investigating locally. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes. This test-case confirm the issue:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class DelayerTests {

    private static MessageGroupStore messageGroupStore = new SimpleMessageStore();

    private static String GROUP_ID = "testGroup";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        messageGroupStore.addMessageToGroup(GROUP_ID, new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
    }

    @Autowired
    private PollableChannel results;

    @Test
    public void testDelayRescheduling() {
        Message<?> receive = this.results.receive(10000);
        assertNotNull(receive);
        assertEquals("foo", receive.getPayload());
        assertEquals(1, messageGroupStore.getMessageGroupCount());
        assertEquals(0, messageGroupStore.getMessageCountForAllMessageGroups());
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableIntegration
    public static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow delayFlow() {
            return flow ->
                      flow.delay(GROUP_ID, (String) null,
                        e -> e.messageStore(messageGroupStore)
                                .id("delayer"))
                        .channel(c -> c.queue("results"));
        }

    }

}
```

Here we go: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/59.

As a workaround we can do this in our `@Configuration`:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationEventMulticaster multicaster;

@PostConstruct
public void setup() {
    this.multicaster.addApplicationListenerBean("delayer.handler");
}
```

Pay attention to the `beanName` to register. This is exactly that `.id("delayer")` from our flow definition plus the `.handler` suffix for the `DelayHandler` bean definition.

Comment: Ok, thanks for investigating this so promptly. I'll use the suggested workaround ;-)